# How to invoke interfaces in Mirth from java instance?

Tags: java, automation, hl7, mirth

I need to create an test automation framework and the goal is to invoke channels created in Mirth test environment with the static HL7 messages(going forward HL7 messages are read from excel sheet) and capture the result coming out of HIE. Iam planning to develop this framework in java and Can anybody let me know where to find libraries or jar files for manipulating HL7 and invoking interfaces in Mirth.

Thanks,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with Mirth today. It might be easier to create or use a simple MLLP submitter ([Hapi would probably be good for this](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/)) from your unit test that can read your messages from the excel file and post them to Mirth.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to control the Mirth channels using com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.ChannelController.getInstance().getDeployedChannelById(channelId)
 but I don't see why you would want to.  I would setup another channel to read the Excel sheet using ApachiPOI classes or just save as a CSV and then have that channel send to the channel you want to test.  I think having the extra channel read a test folder every minute or so and just dropping a pre-made CSV (batch mode if you want more than one message at a time) in when you are ready would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I think one can send a JMS in java to a Mirth channel that receives a JMS message.  I am new to mirth though.

Comment: The Source tab has "JMS Listener" Connector Type selection.